# Share files to local network

Tags: linux-mint, network-shares, file-sharing

What is the easiest way to share a folder or a file to local network from Linux Mint? I want to access it from other computer with Windows that is connected to the same Wi-Fi network.

Comment: I googled "file sharing mint" and got lots of answers. What did you do? Was there something you didn't understand in the answers? They looked straightforward to me.

Comment: "Easiest" is subjective; what ways have you tried already, and why do you find them difficult?

Comment: @AFH, most solutions that I found says: *right click on folder and select **Sharing Options***. But I doesn't have such menu item

Comment: I use Ubuntu Mate, which is not that dissimilar. My default file manager `caja` needs a separate package `caja-share` to show this option: other file managers may need a similar extra. This [answer](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1195234#p1195234) seems to cover the topic quite well. You may not see **Sharing Options** until all the necessary packages are installed and the file manager is restarted.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Linux Mint tutorial](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1954):

*You can share any user directory you wish by using Nemo, the file browser provided by default in Linux Mint.*

*Start Nemo, the file browser and navigate to a directory somewhere below your home that you want to share. Right-Click the directory of choice and select `Properties`. Then take a close look at the "Sharing" tab.*

*Select "Share this Folder".*

*This will let you access the folder from another system as a SMB share. Before you can actually access this you will need a samba password. So create one by going to the command line and typing*

```
$ sudo smbpasswd -a user
```

*where user is your user name on the Linux system.*

*Now you can go to a Windows or OS X, or another Linux machine and access the share on your Linux system. Use the credentials of your Linux username and the smb password you provided when you ran the command above.*

Comment: I didn't have **Nemo** by default (I had Dolphin) so I've installed it. Now I can't find a tab named **Sharing**. Screenshot: https://s23.postimg.org/406wwo10b/Screenshot_20170111_182756.png Should I install any additional application? I'm using KDE desktop if it matters. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nitroshare is probably one of the best tools for sharing files. Check it here: https://nitroshare.net/

It allows any computer on the network with Nitroshare to share directories and send both files and folders to one another when required.

Comment: I can't launch it. I get a message in console `QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set` and then nothing happens. Can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

For viewing share options on right click first open a terminal and then:

1. `sudo apt-get install caja-share`
2. Logoff and login
3. <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
4. `su`
5. `smbd` or `samba`
6. exit from Terminal

After all this the " sharing options" is activated and you can share your folder on the local network and see he shared folder in Windows as well.